# windows 10 wakes up from power save mode after monitor goes into sleep mode

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, sleep, external-display

I set windows 10 to go into power save mode after 10 minutes and I have the 223s7 philips monitor plugged with HDMI.

after 10 min windows send a sleep signal to the monitor and they both go into power save mode, the monitor signals it on the screen ("going into power save mode") and after 5 seconds they both wake up again.
I guess that the monitor sends a signal to windows that wakes it up... but It's just a guess... what could it be?

How can I solve this very annoying situation?

thanks

Comment: I updated the generic monitor intel drivers and now it seems to not behave anymore like that... I will keep on testing it anyway...

Comment: anyway I would like to know any ideas about this strange behaviour

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the monitor was not sending any signal. It must have been an issue with the drivers.

Comment: If you have VESA DPM compliance display card or software installed in your PC, the monitor can automatically reduce its power consumption when not in use. If an input from a keyboard, mouse or other input device is detected, the monitor will 'wake up' automatically. From the 223s7 pdf manual page 19 https://cdn.cnetcontent.com/41/da/41dafc7b-6e3c-449c-b132-090a51b6d873.pdf this may help

Comment: @mic84 thanks but the problem is that it wakes up even without an input...